# how to pass google play games data to another user

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-games

My son is playing games on a tablet configured with my gmail. He is now old enough to get an account of his own. The only problem is that he plays a lot of games via google play games and I wouldn't like all his data to be deleted. Is there a way to transfer all the data to the new account?

Answer (score 1):

No. google is going to be bringing a feature soon that lets you share your apps with up to 6 peoeple. besides that the only option is the illegal option which requires root and to know where the game data is and copy it from one device to another.